# Laravel Validation + Testing, depend field of another field

Tags: laravel

Using `FormRequest`, how do I depend one field's rules on another field's value. I know I could use the `request()` helper to get the data like below, but then it will fail in my tests.

```
return [
    'deposit' => 'sometimes|int|min:100|max:' . request->get('price) * 0.15,
    'price' => 'required|int|min:1000',
];
```

I have dug into the source of the class `FormRequest`, where there is a function called `validationData(). However, this returns an empty array in my tests.

This is how I test my `FormRequest`:

```
$request = new InvoiceRequest;
$validator = \Validator::make($data, $request->rules());
$results = $validator->errors()->has($key);
```

Since `request->get('price)` will always be `null, the deposit field will have a max value of 0 in my tests, while in the controller it will get the price*0.15 as it should.

> Is there a way to achieve this in the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, my solution is that I pass additional data through the `rules()` method like this:

```
public function rules($price = null)
{
    $price = request()->get('price') ?? (int)$price;

    return [
        'deposit' => 'sometimes|int|min:100|max:' . round($price * 0.15),
        'price' => 'required|int|min:1000',
    ];
}
```

And in my test, I just call the `rules()` with my price. This work-around is not perfect but it does the trick. I have additional tests making sure cases when using `request()->get('price')` also works.